# Error al obtener objeto Remoto (GlassFish, EJB)

Tags: jpa, java-ee, glassfish, ejb

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto web (maven), y añadiendo por medio de dependencias a mi archivo pom.xml otro proyecto maven para utilizar todas sus clases...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pretendo hacer, es mostrar en mi proyecto web, una pagina que muestre una lista de clientes, para lo cual tengo una clase llamada "**Persona**", en el proyecto "**AgregarClientes**" y este objeto lo obtengo por medio de una interfaz Remota como se ve en la imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui todo el bien, el problema esta que al momento de obtener la coleccion de objetos persona, GlassFish me genera un error.

El StackTrace que aparece en la consola de GlassFish es el siguiente:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446393 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ADVERTENCIA: 00810057: Could not load class entities.Persona  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe
    at servicio._ClientesService_Wrapper.getClients(servicio/_ClientesService_Wrapper.java)
    at controller.Nuevo.listarPersonas(Nuevo.java:53)
    at controller.Nuevo.doGet(Nuevo.java:32)
**..............................................................etc**
```

Comment: Alguna solución ? llevo días intentando de todo, buscando en foros, pero no he logrado dar con el problema....

Comment: No entendí bien lo que quieres hacer, pero en java todo lo que se manda via internet debe implementar la interface Serializable. Si no pueden ocurrir problemas de comunicacion como el que te ocurre. Ademas el error dice que no puede instanciar entities.Persona ¿Si tiene constructor vacio declarado? Ademas creo que esa clase es la que debería implementar Serializable.

Comment: @abrahamhs Si mi Clase ya implementa la interfaz Serializable, además cuenta con un constructor vacio

Comment: Por eso mismo, no logro entender por cual motivo me genera el error, ya revise mi código varias veces y creo todo esta correcto

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java

Comment: @abrahamhs ya revise, al parecer dice que la interfaz List, no es serializable, lo voy a revisary comento si funciono, gracias

Comment: @abrahamhs ya funcionó, pero el problema no era en la interfaz List, ya que obtenía mi coleccion de objetos, implementando una interfaz que tenia como Remota y la cambia a Local (@Local), y con eso ya me pudo mostrar los datos en mi pagina web.